# Devexpress Layout look and feel does not work on Windows 2003 server?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, devexpress, citrix

I am developing a Delphi 2010 application using the TMS Toolbar and the Devexpress layout control and grid.

I used the styling options the make the program look like office. This works fine on windows 7 and windows XP.

However the program has to run on Citrix (windows 2003 server). On the server the styling options of the TMS components work, but the Devexpress components revert back to the native look and feel.

Does anyone have any tips how to get styling to work on windows 2003 server?

Comment: What version of Devex libraries? Did you ask also to Devex support? They usually answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to Cytrix admin if there are some settings to allow other then default theme on cytrix clients.